# Need to find last updated records in log file

Tags: linux, text-processing

We have a log file where records will be appended to the same file daily, We are not sure about the number of records that gets appended on a particular day. I need to print the records that were last appended to the file.

```
cat file.txt, (yesterday file)
Shyam
Raghu
```

```
cat file.txt, (today file)
Shyam
Raghu
Ravi
```

As we can see Ravi is the record updated recently in the file, I need to print only Ravi.

I have tried using `tail -f` command but I am getting previous day records also as the records updated are dynamic, Is there any script or command which give me only today updated records?

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a sample of the file?

Comment: Short answer is no. The only timestamp information being saved is for the most recent addition, on the file itself. You need to either 1. append a timestamp field, or 2. rotate the logfile to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 41 line TXR Lisp program as a daemon to monitor the log file and produce a version of it with time stamps, in real time.

TXR has very low dependencies and a small memory footprint, yet a lot of capability.

First, the demo:

We start in a state in which `foo` and `bar` do not exist. `foo` will be the log file without stamps. `bar` will be the log file with stamps:

```
$ rm -f foo bar
```

We run the `stamp.tl` program in the background. I didn't put a `#!` (hash bang) line in it (exercise for reader), so we use `txr` on it. The `-d` means it will put itself into the background as a daemon:

```
$ txr stamp.tl -d foo bar
```

OK, let's start making content in `foo`:

```
$ echo "first post" >> foo
$ cat foo
first post
```

What happens in `bar`?

```
$ cat bar
2021-08-20 06:40:06 first post
```

The log line showed up there with a time stamp. Keep going:

```
$ echo "second post" >> foo
$ cat bar
2021-08-20 06:40:06 first post
2021-08-20 06:40:17 second post
$ echo "third post" >> foo
$ cat bar
2021-08-20 06:40:06 first post
2021-08-20 06:40:17 second post
2021-08-20 06:40:24 third post
```

Now, let's try something. Suppose the software which is logging the `foo` log rotates the log. `foo` disappears and then starts again from zero length:

```
$ rm foo
$ echo "rotated" >> foo
$ cat foo
rotated
```

What happens to `bar`?

```
$ cat bar
2021-08-20 06:40:06 first post
2021-08-20 06:40:17 second post
2021-08-20 06:40:24 third post
2021-08-20 06:40:49 rotated
```

As you can see, it has captured the `rotated` line just fine.

Of course, the real solution is to fix the original software that's logging without timestamps, but this could just be the band-aid solution in the meanwhile.

The code follows. The program has three options. In addition to the above `-d` that we used, it has an option to overwrite the target file (default behavior is to append) and an option to use full buffering for writing (default is to use line buffering).

Note that the program doesn't support rotating the output log, because it just opens the file and keeps it open. To support external log rotation, the program would have to open and close the file each time it writes. Or else, implement internal rotation: after so many lines, close the file, do the rotating renames, and re-open it.

```
;; Copyright 2021
;; Kaz Kylheku <kaz@kylheku.com>
;; Vancouver, Canada
;; All rights reserved.
;;
;; Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
;; modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
;;
;; 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
;;    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
;;
;; 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
;;    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
;;    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
;;
;; THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
;; AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
;; IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
;; ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
;; LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
;; CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
;; SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
;; INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
;; CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
;; ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
;; POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

(defun stamp (infile outfile opts)
  (when (and opts.daemonize
             (not (daemon t nil))) ;; don't chdir
    (put-line "failed to daemonize")
    (exit nil))
  (let* ((line-buf (if opts.fully-buffered "" "l"))
         (write-mode (if opts.overwrite `w@{line-buf}` `a@{line-buf}`)))
    (with-resources ((out (open-file outfile write-mode) (close-stream out))
                     (in (open-tail infile) (close-stream in)))
      (whilet ((line (get-line in)))
        (let ((stamp (time-string-local (time) "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
          (put-line `@stamp @line` out))))))

(define-option-struct prog-opts nil
  (w   overwrite        :bool
       "Overwrite the output file instead of appending.")
  (d   daemonize        :bool
       "Run in the background as a daemon")
  (f   fully-buffered   :bool
       "Writes to the output file are flushed whenever\ \
        an I/O buffer fills up. The default behavior is to\ \
        flush after every line.")
  (nil help    :bool
       "List this help text."))

(defvarl prog-name *load-path*)

(defun usage ()
  (put-line "\nUsage:\n")
  (put-line `  @{prog-name} [ options ] <infile> [ <outfile> ]`))

(let ((o (new prog-opts)))
  o.(getopts *args*)
  (when o.help
    (usage)
    o.(opthelp)
    (exit nil))
  (match-case o.out-args
    ((@infile @outfile) (stamp infile outfile o))
    ((@infile) (stamp infile `@infile.stamped` o))
    (@else (usage) (exit nil))))
```